# before_filter and Ajax Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am in the process of refactoring some code and thought that a method that was used in every controller now has it's own class and called using a before_filter within the Application Controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :subtotal

  def subtotal
    @user_subtotal = UserSubtotal::Subtotal.new(current_or_guest_user).subtotal
  end

end

class UserSubtotal::Subtotal
  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def subtotal
    @frame_total = CartItem.frame_price_total(@user)
    @image_size_total = CartItem.image_size_price_total(@user)
    @subtotal = CartItem.subtotal(@frame_total, @image_size_total)
 end
end
```

In my views i am rendering a partial (it tracks the users cart subtotal)

```
<span class="total"><%= render 'shared/cart_amount' %></span>
```

**_cart_amount.html.erb**

```
<%= number_to_currency(@user_subtotal, unit: '£') + ' (excluding shipping)'%>
```

So when adding an item to the cart I am doing this via Ajax and the `create.js.erb` file renders the same partial

**create.js.erb**

```
$(".total").html('<%= j render partial: "shared/cart_amount" %>');
```

**cart_items_controller**

```
def create
  respond_to do |format|
    if @cart_item.save
      format.js { flash.now[:success] = 'Successfully added to cart' }
    else
      format.js { flash.now[:error] = @cart_item.errors.full_messages }
    end
  end
end
```

How can i get the value of `@user_subtotal` to update in this circumstance

I am probably not thinking of something glaringly obvious

Thanks

UPDATE

I think I solved it but whether it's the correct solution I don't know, be interesting to get other peoples thoughts, within my create controller I added

```
@user_subtotal = UserSubtotal::Subtotal.new(current_or_guest_user).subtotal if request.xhr?
```

This gives me a fresh instance of `@user_subtotal`

Answer (score 0):

You could bind to a jQuery click event when something gets added to the cart and then return the value you want to update and simply change it with jquery.

```
 $.ajax({
   type: 'GET', // or whatever you make the route in the controller
   url: "/whatever/route_you_create"
   data: "value to add to existing"
 }).done(function(ajax_response){
   // set .val(ajax_response['num_to_change']) 
 })
```

Update the value in the controller action and save the new value, then return the new value via json.